# Three.js, change the dimension of Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a new starter in ThreeJS and Currently I want to create a ployhedron Geometry with different width, height and length. 
However, every time when I use the initializing method ployhedronGeomotry(), the shape appears with same dimension.

How can I change the width, height and length?

After reading the source codes, the problem appears caused by the radius parameter.

Here is my code:

```html
var verticesOfCube = [
  0.3,0,0.3,    0.3,0,-0.3,    -0.3,0,-0.3,    -0.3,0,0.3,
  0,1.5,0, 0,-1.5,0
  ];

  var indicesOfFaces = [
  0,1,4, 1,2,4,    
  2,3,4, 3,0,4,
  0,1,5, 1,2,5,
  2,3,5, 3,0,5
  ];

  var geometry = new THREE.PolyhedronGeometry( verticesOfCube, indicesOfFaces, 5, 0);
  
  
  // material
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
   color: 0x00ffff, 
   shading: THREE.FlatShading,
   transparent: true,
   opacity: 0.7,
  } );
  
  // mesh
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( mesh );
```

What I want is to set the scale with defined 0.3 and 1.5, However after using THREE.PolyhedronGeometry( verticesOfCube, indicesOfFaces, 5, 0); all dimension become 5.

What I have tried:
Commenting the method: appplyRadius( radius ); in three.js source code and it doesn't work.

Comment: It is advisable to show your code... Usually what you want is achieved like so: `mesh.scale.set( 1, 2, 1 )`, or `geometry.scale( 1, 2, 1 )`.

Comment: (1) Each face must be specified in counter-clockwise winding order. You have not done that. To compensate, you can set `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`. (2) Set `transparent: false` until you get it working correctly.